# How to get the type of configurable item as configurable from Magento sales order for a configurable Item?

Tags: magento

I have the following code to retrieve the type of product from the sales order of the magento.

```
$sku=$item->getSku();
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
echo '<br>'.$product->getTypeID().'<br>';
```

`$item` is the variable which I got from sales order.

Now if I try to get the details of the sales order which contains a configurable product,it prints type as **simple**. Then I tried to get the name of the prodcut from the following code.

```
echo $product->getName();
```

It displayed the name of the simple product associated with the configurable item.

What should I do to get the type of the Item as **configurable.**

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento stores two item records for each configurable product on an order. The most common way to get only the configurable items from the pair is to call `$order->getAllVisibleItems()`, which will return an array of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item` objects with only the item records that are visible to the customer.

However, if you only have the simple item from the pair you can also get the parent product like this:

```
/**
 * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
 * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $item
 * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 */
if ($parentId = $item->getParentItemId()) {
    $parent = $order->getItemById($parentId);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parent->getProductId());
}
```

Comment: If I write `echo $product->getSku();` ,I am getting nothing displayed.But if I write `$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);` `echo $item->getName();` it shows the name of the configurable product.....

Comment: Please help me on that

Comment: @PavanPrakash - You should get the SKU field of the configurable product  in my example with `$product->getSku()` or `$parent->getSku()`. If you are not getting what you expect, there may be some confusion in which product is actually on the order. You can get the info about the order items directly from the database with this query (add your own $orderID): `SELECT item_id, parent_item_id, sku, product_type, product_id FROM sales_flat_order_item oi INNER JOIN sales_flat_order o ON oi.order_id = o.entity_id WHERE o.increment_id = $orderID OR o.entity_id = $orderID;` Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code,

> $product->getProductType()

Comment: Try $product->getResource()->getTypeId()